# Find out an executable program is memeory intensive or computation intensive

Tags: memory, profiling, processor, instruction-set

I have an executable program file and I am using SimpleScaler to profile the program. How could I know the program is memory intensive or computation intensive. I got data like " 152k # total size of memory pages allocated
"

Note: I know the concept of memory intensive and computation intensive and I could able to say a program is memory intensive or not by seeing the code. But here I am running the binary file only I have no idea about the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer in Windows is, run the task manager and see if the program uses 100% of one or more cores. If so, it is compute-bound.

I could give you a better answer, but only if you had the source code. Sometimes people think they can't get the source code when in fact they can.
Then I would simply use [*this can't fail technique*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).
The program is spending a lot of time doing *something*.
If it spends a lot of time doing memory allocation and deletion (`new` and/or `delete`), then that's the problem.
If it spends a lot of time executing computational code, then that's where to look.